# How to read checkbox value on post?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a form in my template contains two checkboxes. If user does not check checkbox than there is nothing in POST object. If user checks it then request.POST.get("check1") returns empty string. When i'm creating object and filling a Boolean field, it becomes False because of empty string.

```
class NewCustomer(View):
    def get(self, request):
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("Customer/NewCustomer.html", c)

    def post(self, request):
        customer = Customer.create(request.POST.get("name", ""), request.POST.get("surname", ""),
                                   request.POST.get("phoneNumber", ""), request.POST.get("address", ""),
                                   request.POST.get("sendSms", ""), request.POST.get("sendEmail", False),
                                   request.POST.get("email", False))
        return redirect("GetCustomer", customerId=customer.id)
```

sendSms and sendEmail are checkboxes.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Name = models.TextField(blank=False)
    Surname = models.TextField(blank=False)
    PhoneNumber = models.TextField()
    Address = models.TextField()
    SendSms = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    SendEmail = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    Email = models.TextField()
    Created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, name, surname, phoneNumber, address , sendSms, sendEmail, email):
        customer = cls(Name=name, Surname=surname, PhoneNumber=phoneNumber
                        , Address=address, SendSms=sendSms, SendEmail=sendEmail
                        , Email=email)
        customer.save()
        return customer
```

What is the correct way to read checkbox and assign value to my boolean fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
is_checked = "check1" in request.POST
```